# Hybris trigger SOLR index programmatically

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, solrj, hybris-data-hub

Is there any service on Hybris that triggers the SOLR full/update indexation? I need to execute SOLR indexation programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `indexerService`, this bean contains several methods to perform Solr index operations

See: https://help.sap.com/doc/a4265d5ea8314eb2929e6cf6fb8e35a5/1811/en-US/de/hybris/platform/solrfacetsearch/indexer/IndexerService.html